# Implementing surjective data structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am interested in performing the following operations on a set of data.

First, we are given a set of keys, as an example:

```
vector<int> keys{1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Each of these keys is understood to be pointing to a unique entry (which is not important to specify, rather what is important is the relation whether each key is pointing to a separate entry, or some keys are pointing to the same entry). Initially, we do not know whether any key is pointing to the same entry or not, so we start out with a data structure that treats all entries as separate for each key:

```
surjectiveData<int> data;
data.populateUnique(keys.begin(),keys.end());
```

Graphically, we can illustrate the current state of `data` as

[image]

where we use labels `a,b,c,d,e,f` to keep track of the unique entries in `data`. Now, consider adding additional information on which keys are pointing to the same entry. For example:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> identifications{make_pair(1,2),make_pair(3,4),make_pair(2,4),make_pair(5,6)};
data.couple(identifications.begin(),indentifications.end());
```

The `couple` method of `surjectiveData` goes through the pairs provided and makes them point to the same unique entry. Graphcally, the four `identifications` would in turn change `data` as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

and now there are only two unique entries in `data`, which here we denote `abcd` and `ef`. Note that once two or more keys point to the same entry, it does not matter which of these keys is identified with which of separate keys, all of them point to the same entry after identification.

Now that we are done with specifying key identifications, we could think of using `data` as follows. For example, we could ask what is the effective number of unique remaining entries

```
cout<<data.size()<<endl; // 2
```

Or, we could iterate through the entries and check how many keys point to each of them

```
for(auto it=data.begin();it!=data.end();it++){
    cout<<it->size()<<" ";// 4 2
}
```

Ideally, internally the structure should take constant time for each identification, if possible.

I tried to search for such a data structure in the standard library, but could not find any. Did I miss it? Perhaps there is a smart way to implement it based on more basic objects? If so, what would be a minimal example for integers?

Comment: You did not miss anything. There is no such C++ container. The C++ library containers implement basic container functionality, with several variations of each container's basic properties, complexities, and use cases. To implement some kind of an exotic container like the one described, one starts with C++ library's containers, and combines them together in order to achieve the desired semantics. I can think of several ways of doing something like this, but this is just too broad to have a specific, authoritative answer. Can you tailor your lengthy description to form a more specific question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your comment! Mainly, when trying to implement it myself, I am struggling with making each identification step take constant time regardless of how many keys are being identified with how many other keys. It would be a huge help if you could give me a hint on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operations you describe can be supported with a disjoint set data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

This is a linked data structure that supports 3 operations:

1. makeSet() creates a new singleton set and returns its element
2. union(a,b) given two elements, merges the sets that contain them.  One element of each set will be the "representative" of that set
3. find(a) returns the representative of the set that contains a.

All operations take pretty much constant amortized time.

I usually implement this data structure in a *single vector*, where each array index denotes is a set element.  If its value is >0, then it's a set representative and the value is the size of the set.  If its value is < 0 then its value is ~p, where p is its "parent" element in the same set.  Sometimes I use the 0 value for "uninitialized".

It's not hard to keep track of the number of sets.

in C++, my usual implementation would look like this:

```
class DijointSets {
    unsigned num_sets;
    std::vector<int> sets;

    public:

    // Create a new singleton set and return its element
    unsigned make_set() {
        unsigned ret = (unsigned)sets.size();
        sets.push_back(1);
        ++num_sets;
        return ret;
    }

    // Find the representative element of an element's set
    unsigned find(unsigned x) {
        int p = sets[x];
        if (p>=0) {
            return x;
        }
        p = find(~p);
        sets[x] = ~p;  //might be the same
        return p;
    }
    
    // Merge the sets that contain two elements
    // returns true if a merge was done
    boolean union(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
        a = find(a);
        b = find(b);
        if (a==b) {
            return false;
        }
        if (sets[a] > sets[b]) {
            sets[a] += sets[b]; //add sizes
            sets[b] = ~(int)a;
        } else {
            sets[b] += sets[a]; //add sizes
            sets[a] = ~(int)b;
        }
        --num_sets;
        return true;
    }

    // get the size of an element's set
    unsigned set_size(x) {
        return sets[find(x)];
    }

    // get the number of sets 
    unsigned set_count() {
        return num_sets;
    }
}
```